# Check if there is at least one checked checkbox in two windows forms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, class

I have a project for school in visual studio, windows forms app, C#, which has 4 forms that are connected.

The connecton from the 1st to the 2nd, and from the 3rd to the 4th form was easy to make. But I'm not so sure how to make a connection from the 2nd to the 3rd form.

My 1st and 2nd form have checkboxes, 12 in total - 6 on each form, and they aren't in a checkbox list (if this matters). So here comes my problem...
The app is something like a little online shop. The 1st and the 2nd form act like pages, where you can see and choose something to buy. When you're done choosing, you can go to the 3rd "page"/form by clicking a button. But in order to go to the 3rd form, I have to check if there is at least one checked checkbox in the 1st **or** the 2nd "page". If there isn't at least 1 checked box, it must show an error message. I asked my teacher about how I could possibly do it (since she hasn't shown us how to do something similar). She told me to create a new class where I could write the code for the check, but nothing more.

I looked around, but couldn't really find a solution to my problem.

Anything little could help, I just need some guidance that my teacher couldn't provide me...
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this meets the requirements of your exercise, but have you considered putting "Form1" and "Form2" on the same `Form` and simply use two `Panel` toggling the visibility of the panels as needed. That way all the components are on the same `Form` and validating the Checkboxes becomes quite easy.

Comment: If you were using [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), you could share the same data between the forms, making this kind of requirement easy.

Comment: @Johnny Pickles, is any update?  Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Application.OpenForms method and linq to get current form control state.

Here is a code example you can refer to:

Form1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    int count1 = form1.Controls
        .OfType<CheckBox>()
        .Where(i => i.Checked)
        .Count();
    Form2 form2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
    int count2 = form2.Controls
        .OfType<CheckBox>()
        .Where(i => i.Checked)
        .Count();
    int totalcount = count1 + count2;
    if(totalcount<1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must choose at least one");
    }
    else
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        form3.Show();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]